# How to dynamically set focus to next text box in ui:repeat

Tags: javascript, jsf, jquery-plugins, focus

I have one text box immediately after that one button. If i click on that button dynamically i get one more text box, but the focus is not coming to new text box. Can any one suggest something.

Thanks in advance
Venkat

Answer (score 2):

You need to execute [`element.focus()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/element.focus) on the new texbox after its insertion to give it focus.

E.g.

```
var element = document.getElementById('newElementId');
element.focus();
```

Also available in jQuery

```
$('#newElementId').focus();
```